# Proving that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}+ \left(\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\right)^2\le \max_{t\in [a,b]}\{f'(t)+(g'(t))^2\}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, inequality

Let $f,g\in C^1([a,b])$ with $a<b$ then prove that

> $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}+ \left(\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\right)^2\le \max_{t\in [a,b]}\{f'(t)+(g'(t))^2\}$$

It smells  like there is some mean value theorem going around. But I tried it as follows:

Indeed, it springs from mean value theorem that There exists  $c_1,c_2\in (a,b)$ such that

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = f'(c_1)~~~ and 
~~~~\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a} = g'(c_2)$$

> Then I have  $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}+ \left(\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\right)^2= f'(c_1)+(g'(c_2))^2\le \max_{t\in [a,b]}\{f'(t)\}+\max_{t\in [a,b]}\{(g'(t)^2)\}$$

Which is however not the required inequality.

Can anyone help? how can I improve this ?

Comment: Either this is a very, very weird question, or else you're messing with symbols: the inequality is senseless as $\;g\;$ doesn't appear on the left hand...and twice you wrote the same!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

\begin{align*}
&\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}+\left(\dfrac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}\right)^{2}\\
&=\int_{a}^{b}f'(t)\dfrac{dt}{b-a}+\left(\int_{a}^{b}g'(t)\dfrac{dt}{b-a}\right)^{2}\\
&\leq\int_{a}^{b}f'(t)\dfrac{dt}{b-a}+\int_{a}^{b}(g'(t))^{2}\dfrac{dt}{b-a}\\
&\leq\max_{t\in[a,b]}\{f'(t)+(g'(t))^{2}\}\int_{a}^{b}\dfrac{dt}{b-a}\\
&=\max_{t\in[a,b]}\{f'(t)+(g'(t))^{2}\}.
\end{align*}

Comment: No comment Jessen inequality thanks

Answer (score -1):

Treat $\max$ as $\sup$, then apply then fact that $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$, for $A,B$ be nonempty bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ and $A+B=\{a+b:a\in A,b\in B\}$

Comment: This is pure bluff, a false hint. -1

Comment: this answer is not appropriate to the question. can you use your statement to give an answer?

Comment: Moreover, your hint is pointless. note the  following : There is a significant  difference between $$  \max_{t\in [a,b]}\{f'(t)+(g'(t))^2\}$$ and $$  \max_{s,t\in [a,b]}\{f'(s)+(g'(t))^2\}$$ in which the latest incorporate your statement but does not fit the question itself.

Comment: @Medo read my last comment. you can see the difference.

Comment: @ Guy Fsone. Thank you for the remark. Indeed the question asks for the stronger (smaller) bound $\max_{t\in [a,b]}\{ f^{\prime}(t)+(g^{\prime}(t))^2\}$ not the weaker (larger) bound $$\max_{s,t\in [a,b]}\{ f^{\prime}(s)+(g^{\prime}(t))^2\}=\max_{s\in [a,b]}\{ f^{\prime}(s)\}+\max_{t\in [a,b]}\{(g^{\prime}(t))^2\}=$$